# Display based on Django WagtailCMS SITE_ID

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, wagtail, wagtail-snippet

How can I create an `if` block to display one of my sidemenu's based on the WagtailCMS SITE_ID?

Tried this, but it doesn't work

```
{% if settings.SITE_ID == 1 %}
   {% include 'includes/_home-sidebar-left.html' %}
{% else %}
   {% include 'includes/_home-sidebar.html' %}
{% endif }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is a page template, you can access the current site through the page object with [page.get_site()](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.9/reference/pages/model_reference.html#wagtail.wagtailcore.models.Page.get_site).

That being said, you'll end up with magic strings/numbers (for checking the site ID or name) in your templates. One way to get around that would be to use the [wagtail.contrib.settings](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.9/reference/contrib/settings.html) module.

After setting up the module correctly, create a settings object (which will appear in the admin) in `myapp/wagtail_hooks.py`:

```
from wagtail.contrib.settings.models import BaseSetting, register_setting


@register_setting
class LayoutSettings(BaseSetting):
    POSITION_LEFT = 'left'
    POSITION_RIGHT = 'right'
    POSITIONS = (
        (POSITION_LEFT, 'Left'),
        (POSITION_RIGHT, 'Right'),
    )
    sidebar_position = models.CharField(
        max_length=10,
        choices=POSITIONS,
        default=POSITION_LEFT,
    )
```

And use the settings in the templates `myapp/templates/myapp/mytemplate.html`

```
{% if settings.myapp.LayoutSettings.sidebar_position == 'left' %}
   {% include 'includes/_home-sidebar-left.html' %}
{% else %}
   {% include 'includes/_home-sidebar.html' %}
{% endif }
```